# Ionic release : Android package can not build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, release

We are trying to build an apk package for a new version on android store.
We got the following error :
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /usr/src/app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19, or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures) * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s 23 actionable tasks: 23 executed (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /usr/src/app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. /usr/src/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:37:5-74 Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /usr/src/app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19, or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures) FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /usr/src/app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19, or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures) * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/src/app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23) at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5) (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

We have no clue why and tried to debug it with the ionic dashboard unsuccessfuly. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Increase your android-minSdkVersion to 19 inside your `config.xml` of your ionic project.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```